# Toggle function in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have got an issue with the md side nav implementation in Angular 2 in toggling

In My main.html I have:

```
<md-sidenav #sidenav mode="over" class="app-sidenav" md-component-id="left" md-disable-backdrop md-whiteframe="4">

<menu-comp></menu-comp>

</md-sidenav>
```

In the same main.html I have,

```
<button class="app-icon-button menu-button table" (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
```

Which works just fine. But, in the menu-comp.html as below,

I have a button, as follows:

```
<button type="button" class="close side-bar-close"  (click)="sidenav.toggle()" aria-label="Close"> </button>
```

That doesn't function and throws an error

> Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined

I did try using the below approach but it did not work either.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular-material2/Zf0YiWc4aA4

Any suggestions as how to invoke sidenav.toggle from menu-comp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user clicks on the button, emit an event, something like **toogleSidenav**, then in you main component template you can:

```
<menu-comp (toogleSidenav)="sidenav.toogle()"></menu-comp>
```